# Regex for non-consecutive upper-case words

Tags: regex, notepad++

Here's one for you **Regex wizards.**

This is for use within Notepad++, i.e. it is entered directly into the search and replace dialog.

I need to match and highlight isolated words of capital letters of two or more characters that are nested in a string, but the capitalised words must not be consecutive, they must always be surrounded by lower case words ( or lower case nouns with first letter capitalised) or be at the start or end of a sentence followed or preceded by lower case word ( or again a word with the first letter capitalised.

ie.

Given the string  **This is a sentence WITH some capitalised WORDS IN it.**

I need to match the "**WITH**" **but not "WORDS" or "IN"** because WORDS is followed by another capitalised word and IN is preceded by the same.

The string should be assumed to be multi-line.

I have tried with lookaheads but failed dismally

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

:-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for surrounding characters with negative lookahead and negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![A-Z]\s)\b[A-Z]+\b(?!\s[A-Z])
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/cI5dC7)

*Notepad++ v6.5.1 & works on multi-line purposes too*

[image: Notepad++ v6.5.1]

Comment: Sorry, no negative lookbehind in Notepad++

Comment: @Jerry yes. also added the image.

Comment: @revo Ahh, the one that was released yesterday does allow lookbehinds. Though Ωmega's point is valid as well.

Comment: Many thanks to all who answered, excellent work!   Now here's a further twist.  How can that be negated to match all words in caps EXCEPT the isoloted capitalised words? I tried changing negatives to positives and could not make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried that regex and it works for me when I use the 'Mark' feature of the Notepad++ Find/Replace. I'm not sure if you have any other test cases though.

```
(?:[[:lower:]][^A-Za-z]*|\A)\K\b[[:upper:]]+\b(?=[^A-Za-z]*[[:lower:]]|\Z)
```

I'm using `\A` and `\Z` because you mentioned multilines.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bC1xW1) (with some explanations there).

Be sure to check 'Match case'.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

EDIT: As per update, to inverse the highlighting, I came up with that one... a bit lengthy:

```
[^A-Z]+|(?:(?=[A-Z]*[a-z])\b[A-Za-z]+\b)|(?:\b[A-Z]+\b(?=[^a-z]+[A-Z])(?:[^a-z]*[A-Z]+)*)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yS7dX8)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
(^|\.\s+|[a-z]\s+)([A-Z]+)(\.|\s+[a-z]|$)
```

That matches: a period or start-of-line or end of a lowercase word; followed by an uppercase word; followed by a period, end-of-line or start of a lowercase word.

The word itself is matched in group 2. If Notepad++ supports lookaround assertions, you can do this so that the only captured word is the single capitalized word:

```
(?:^|\.\s+|[a-z]\s+)([A-Z]+)(?:\.|\s+[a-z]|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
(?<![[:upper:]]) ([[:upper:]]+) (?!([[:upper:]]| )+)
```

this will also select anything your locale considers to be uppercase, not just A-Z

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?:[^A-Z]\s+|[^a-zA-Z\s]|\A)\K[A-Z]+\b(?!\s+[A-Z])
```

Comment: @revo: no <°)))))))))>

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't support non-capturing group `(?:` either

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte [FWIW](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions#Readability_enhancements)

Comment: It doesn't mention it in the wiki, but non-capture group has been working in N++ for as long as I used it.

Comment: @Jerry it has another usage : `(?:flags-not-flags ...), (?:flags-not-flags:...)
Applies flags and not-flags to search inside the parentheses. Such a construct may have flags and may have not-flags`

Comment: @revo The syntax is usually `(?L)` where L is a letter (or more) like `i`, `g`, `m` etc... It seems there are some typos in the docs ...

Comment: @Jerry the way Casimir used is existed in PCRE but doesn't work in notepad++ and I didn't found about non-capturing groups in its documents

Comment: @revo Try to make a simple find with `(?:is)` on OP's sample line and see if it works, i.e. highlights all the occurrences of `is`. Then put `isis` somewhere in the sentence and try with `(?:is){2}`.

Comment: @HamZa: Indeed, it seems to be a typo. I think that this paragraph try to describe the possibility for a non-capturing group to have modifiers at the begining (a kind of shortcut for `(?:(?is)...)`). However the correct syntax is `(?is:...)` but not `(?:is:...)`.