# Regex for non-consecutive upper-case words PART DEUX

Tags: regex, notepad++

Very many thanks to all those who answered part 1 of this question see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527107/regex-for-non-consecutive-upper-case-words)

The regex that worked for me was

```
(?<![A-Z]\s)\b[A-Z]+\b(?!\s[A-Z])
```

The question now is how to do the inverse, i.e. given the string

**This is a different sentence WITH a few CAPITAL WORDS here AND THERE ACROSS multiple LINES.**

How to match "**CAPITAL WORDS**"  and "**AND THERE ACROSS**" but not match "**WITH**"  or "**LINES**"  as they are isolated with lower case words either side, or they could be at the end of the start of a sentence.

I tried changing from negative to positive lookarounds and altering the [A-Z] to [a-z]  but again failed spectacularly

Any help would be much appreciated once again.

Comment: Could you ask less Frenchily? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two consecutive upper-case words:

```
 [A-Z]{2,}(?:\s+[A-Z]{2,})+
```

---

```
 [A-Z]{2,}           # first word (At least two letters)
 (?:                 # do not capture this group
    \s+[A-Z]{2,}     #                 (whitespace and a word)
 )+                  # one or more of /
```

---

```
In [52]: re.findall(r'[A-Z]{2,}(?:\s+[A-Z]{2,})+', 'CAPITAL Words This is a different sentence WITH a few CAPITAL\nWORDS here AND THERE ACROSS multiple LINES.')
Out[52]: ['CAPITAL\nWORDS', 'AND THERE ACROSS']
```

Comment: Almost there. That will match the capital letter at the start of the next word as well.  Caps words must be at least two letter long, and also it ac't match across a line break, i.e. WORD \n Next word where the N is capitalised

Comment: Ok think I have it [A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]{2,})+

Comment: Yep, edited. First word should be 2+ letters as well?

Comment: Curious though. What's that Regex analysis app you are using?

Comment: That's just a Python shell I had open, it's not a regex analysis app

Comment: Yeh, sort of Voodoo ;-)